# Custom list adapter onClick method returning a null view id

Tags: android, onclick, listadapter

In creating a custom list adapter to be able to click different elements in a single row entry and start different activities, I ran across a problem where my findViewById() method was returning null. Additionally, only the first item in my ListView calls the onClick method; the other rows don't register clicks.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

Context context;
TextView habitId;
Intent intent;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.habit_entry, null);
    }

    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.habitTitle);
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.plus);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.habitTitle:
            Log.d("Test", "habitid = " + v.findViewById(R.id.habitId));
            break;
        case R.id.plus:
            Log.d("Test", "plus clicked");
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

When the code is run, the habitTitle case of onClick prints

```
D/NULL: habitid = null
```

habit_entry

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
    android:id="@+id/plus"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:background="#9bfcff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/habitId"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="difficulty"
    android:id="@+id/habitDifficulty"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/habitTitle"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/habitTitle"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/plus"
    android:layout_above="@id/habitDifficulty"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:text="Your new habits go here!"
    android:id="@+id/habitTitle"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="#444444"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:allowUndo="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="frequency"
    android:id="@+id/habitFrequency"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

call in MainActivity

```
if(habitList.size() != 0) {
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        ListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(
                this, habitList, R.layout.habit_entry, new String[]{"habitId", "title", "difficulty", "frequency"}, new int[]{
                R.id.habitId, R.id.habitTitle, R.id.habitDifficulty, R.id.habitFrequency});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The list populates perfectly, so I'm not sure why I'm having so much trouble with my adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems here. You are inflating the `View` yourself and then returning the `View` returned by calling `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`. You should instead rely on `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` to create the `View` for you since you are using the default implementation like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    v.findViewById(R.id.habitTitle)
            .setOnClickListener(this);

    v.findViewById(R.id.plus)
            .setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
}
```

Also `v.findViewById(R.id.habitId));` is returning null inside `onClick()` because the variable `v` itself is the `TextView` with id = R.id.habitId.

Comment: Haha yeah in hindsight I can see why inflating a view and then just returning a different one was a problem.. Thanks a lot for your insight. I ended up adding habitId, and a couple other elements to a table row so I could click the whole portion and findViewById() a single element in it. Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

You set the visibility of the habitId textview to gone.
The textview will not be inflated and is null.
You can read more information about visibility in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility)

Comment: This was not an issue, in case anyone comes along looking for a solution to my question as well.